# How to activate an activity using a local notification created from a remote notification

Tags: c#, android, notifications, push-notification, xamarin

I have successfully created a local notification that starts an activity, but for some reason when this local notification is created *from within the handler of a remote notification* the activity is not started when the local notification is tapped by the user. No error or exception seems to be thrown.

Below is the code that creates the local notification. Note I'm using Xamarin.
I wonder if it is perhaps somehow permissions related (remote notification handlers maybe cannot create intents to start activities?).

```
private void CreateNotification(string title, string desc) {
    var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ConversationActivity));

    var stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
    stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ConversationActivity)));
    stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(uiIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .SetAutoCancel(true) // Remove the notification once the user touches it
        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .SetContentTitle(title)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.AppIcon)
        .SetContentText(desc)
        .SetDefaults((int)(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate))
        ;

    // Set the notification info
    // we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
    // when the notification is tapped.
    var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
    notificationManager.Notify(1, notification.Build());
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm still not sure what was wrong with my original attempt, but I did find out I could fix it by changing the `Intent` to use a component name instead of an action or activity type:

```
    private void SendNotification() {
        var nMgr = (NotificationManager)this.GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        var notification = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.AppIcon, "Incoming Dart");
        var intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName(this, "dart.androidapp.ContactsActivity"));
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this, "You've got something to read", "You have received a message", pendingIntent);
        nMgr.Notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @CRSardar. But do you have any idea why activity types or action names don't work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call it with typeof(...) as well. The code you posted first is quite different from the latter. Try if this works for you:

```
private void SendNotification() 
{
    var nMgr = (NotificationManager)this.GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    var notification = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.AppIcon, "Incoming Dart");
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ContactsActivity));
    //intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName(this, "dart.androidapp.ContactsActivity"));
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this, "You've got something to read", "You have received a message", pendingIntent);
    nMgr.Notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: That looks very much like my very first iteration (not posted), and it works fine -- except when executing within the context of a remote notification handler.

Answer (score -1):

Hello Andrew for me bellow is working fine

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Hello Chitta!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"jdsjdjbdf@gmail.com"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello CR!");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "This is the body of email");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Send an e-mail", "Ha ha", pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(742134, notification);
```

Are talking about something else?

Comment: The question wasn't about sending an email. It was about popping up one of my own activities.

Comment: Can you please explain your use case in little bit details (stape by sate)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it more than I have. I have a remote notification that should create a local notification that, when the user taps it, should launch one of my activities.